# Can properties such as memory usage of a function be expressed in a dependently typed language?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming, dependent-types, inductive-datatypes

Suppose one wants to reason about properties of code beyond things like totality and functional purity - one also cares about the memory consumption, or algorithmic complexity of a function. Can this be done through dependent typing and effects systems?

Comment: In this [video](https://youtu.be/4i7KrG1Afbk?t=1258) Brian McKenna provides an example of encoding time complexity into types.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it can.  While conceptually it's not that difficult, it hasn't been studied all that much.  One aspect of the field is cost semantics such as the research done by [Guy Blelloch](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/).

In the vein of the video Anton mentioned is Daniellson's work in [Lightweight Semiformal Time Complexity Analysis for Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-popl2008.html).  This does indeed use a monad to carry around a cost per operation.  A similar monad, at the semantic level, is used in [Denotational cost semantics for functional languages with inductive types](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01949).  Here's a 2016 paper doing something similar in Coq, [A Coq Library For Internal Verification of Running-Times](http://www.eecs.northwestern.edu/~robby/pubs/papers/flops2016-mfnff.pdf).

The NuPRL people have also long been interested in doing things like this.  In [Expressing Computational Complexity in Contstructive Type Theory](http://www.nuprl.org/documents/Constable/expressingcomputational.pdf), which basically amounts to calculating over a structured operational semantics.  Where it gets a bit more interesting is that you can reflect the language semantics into the language.  The example in the final section, section 12, of [Naive Computational Type Theory](http://www.nuprl.org/documents/Constable/NaiveTypeTheoryPreface.html) illustrates and discusses this sort of thing.